# Participle Phrase

Tags: grammar

> My father had to comfort my sister, terrified after watching a scary movie.

In this sentence, if the comma is not used between "**my sister, terrified**", then it will be wrong?
because it(participle) occurs immediately after noun that it modify.

Comment: This seems like a rule of language that is, at best, misguided. Punctuation is intended to aid the reader. In context, removing the "," is not going to confuse the reader into believing your sister is named Terrified. Unless you also capitalize Terrified, and even then it's a "trick" to capture attention.

Comment: Even with the comma, the sentence could use some modification. For example, replace the comma with "who was" or some such change.

Comment: Yes, the sentence definitely requires a comma. Google **participial phrases** to see numerous examples illustrating the rule.

Comment: Did you create the example sentence? If not, who wrote it and where dis you read it (or hear it)  please? In future, please use blockquote syntax for examples, not code syntax. See [Formatting your posts](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4799/91457) for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a comma to offset the phrase describing your sister.

However, this sentence is very unusual and awkward. It would be more likely to see:

> Terrified after watching a scary movie, my sister had to be comforted by my father.

That sentence also requires a comma in a similar place.

Answer (score 0):

Adjectives usually have to go *before* the noun they describe. That is the case with 'terrified'. If you removed the comma then you would no longer have a participle phrase, the adjective would follow the noun and the sentence would be grammatically incorrect for that reason alone.

You could say:

> My father had to comfort my terrified sister after watching a scary movie.

Most people would find that acceptable, but of course, your sister probably isn't *always* terrified. The original is better at showing that she was terrified by the movie she watched. In effect, it is saying:

> My father had to comfort my sister *who was* terrified after watching a scary movie.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence:

> (1) My father had to comfort my sister, terrified after watching a scary movie.

According to some authorities, correct grammar requires the comma after "sister*", to set off the ***participial phrase***. However, others say that when a participial phrase directly follows the noun that the phrase modifies, no comma is needed. Yet others say that no comma is needed when when the phrase directly follows the noun being modified, **AND** the phrase is "restrictive", that is,  essential to the meaning of the sentence, no comma is needed, but if the phrase is "non-restrictive", that is, it adds additional but non-essential information, a comma should still be used.

Some sources taking the position that  a comma is not always needed include:

- [Grammar-monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm)
- [Your Dictionary](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/sentences/participial-phrases.html)
- [Perdue Writing Lab](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html)

In the example sentence, the phrase "*terrified after watching a scary movie" is **non**-restrictive, because

> (2) My father had to comfort my sister

is a complete, valid sentences.Therefore, many authorities would agree that the comma in (1) is needed. therefoe, the sentence withot the comma

> (3) My father had to comfort my sister terrified after watching a scary movie.

might be technically incorrect, but is likely to be correctly understood by most fluent or semi-fluent speakers. The idea that someone might think that the sister's name is "Terrified" wouls occur only in a comedy sketch such as the classic ["Who's on First?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_on_First%3F)